# Problem with GTK applications

Tags: arch-linux, gtk

I did an upgrade with `yaourt -Syuu` but when I rebooted, my Xfce didn't work. So I installed KDE and it worked perfectly.

When I tried to run firefox, this is the output:

```
process:5495): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' 
failed
firefox: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 If you want 
: undefined symbol: hb_buffer_set_cluster_level
```

with mousepad:

```
(mousepad:5517): GtkSourceView-CRITICAL **: gtk_source_style_scheme_get_id: assertion 'GTK_IS_SOURCE_STYLE_SCHEME (scheme)' failed

(mousepad:5517): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(mousepad:5517): GtkSourceView-CRITICAL **: gtk_source_style_scheme_get_id: assertion 'GTK_IS_SOURCE_STYLE_SCHEME (scheme)' failed

(mousepad:5517): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(mousepad:5517): GtkSourceView-CRITICAL **: gtk_source_style_scheme_get_id: assertion 'GTK_IS_SOURCE_STYLE_SCHEME (scheme)' failed
mousepad: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_buffer_set_cluster_level
```

and chromium:

```
/usr/lib/chromium/chromium --ppapi-flash-    path=/usr/lib/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=18.0.0.233: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_buffer_set_cluster_level
```

Searching a while I found `libpangoft2-1.0.so` is in  lib32-pango or Pango.

```
sudo pacman -S lib32-pango
advertencia: lib32-pango-1.36.8-1 está actualizado -- reinstalando
resolviendo dependencias...
buscando conflictos entre paquetes....

Paquetes (1) lib32-pango-1.36.8-1

Tamaño total de la instalación:  0,50 MiB
Tamaño neto tras actualizar:    0,00 MiB

:: ¿Continuar con la instalación? [S/n] S
(1/1) comprobando las claves del depósito            [############################] 100%
(1/1) verificando la integridad de los paquetes      [############################] 100%
(1/1) cargando los archivos de los paquetes          [############################] 100%
(1/1) comprobando conflictos entre archivos          [############################] 100%
(1/1) comprobando el espacio disponible en disco     [############################] 100%
(1/1) reinstalando lib32-pango                       [############################] 100%
sbin/ldconfig: El fichero /usr/lib/libtracker-miner-1.0.so.0 está vacío, no se comprueba.
sbin/ldconfig: El fichero /usr/lib/libtracker-miner-1.0.so está vacío, no se comprueba.
sbin/ldconfig: El fichero /usr/lib/libtracker-control-1.0.so.0.600.0 está vacío, no se comprueba.
sbin/ldconfig: El fichero /usr/lib/libtracker-miner-1.0.so.0.600.0 está vacío, no se comprueba.
sbin/ldconfig: El fichero /usr/lib/libtracker-control-1.0.so.0 está vacío, no se comprueba.
```

Also, I tried reinstalling glib2, glib gtk and gtk2 but none of it worked.

Comment: Don't upgrade your system with yaourt. That way of upgrading is completely unsupported and unofficial. No wonder Xfce4 broke.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same failure message from several Applications (!) when I upgraded `pango` these days (on OpenSuSE_Tumbleweed).

In the OpenSuSE mailing list is a thread about the same problem with the AcrobatReader. There I figured out, that it has to do with dependencies from Pango to Harfbuzz ("`hb_buffer` . . .").
So I upgraded `libharfbuzz` from 0.9.9 to 1.0.3. and everything worked fine again.